# Тестирование модулей, использующих модели mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, юнит-тесты, mongoose

Пишу юнит-тесты для модулей, использующие модели [`mongoose`](http://mongoosejs.com/).

Эти модели *могут* содержать пользовательские методы.

Нужно заменить реальные вызовы методов моделей (`create`, `read`, `update`) их стабами.

- Нашел библиотеку [`mongoose-mock`](https://github.com/JohanObrink/mongoose-mock)
- Использую ее следующим образом:

```js
// require часть
var proxyquire =  require('proxyquire')
var rewire =  require('rewire')
var mongooseMock = require('mongoose-mock')
    
// before(Each) часть:
// Использует 2 DI библиотеки

myModel = proxyquire('../lib/models/my.model', {'mongoose': mongooseMock})
    
// rewire позволяет получать доступ к приватным членам (методам, переменным)
// тестируемого модулкя
myMod = rewire('./lib/myMod.js') // Тестируемый модуль.
```

Определение `myMod.js` выглядит следующим образом:

`var MyModel = require('../lib/models/my.model')`

Определение модели `my.model`:

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema,
... // Другие require-зависимости, которые нужно стабить

var MyModelSchema = new Schema({..})

MyModelSchema.statics.myCustomModelMethod =  function(...){...}

module.exports = mongoose.model('MyModel', MyModelSchema)
```

Вопросы:

- Как можно сделать по-другому, избавившись от зависимостей `proxyquire` и `mongoose-mock`. Зависимость `rewire` стандартна для всех моих unit-тестов
- Существует ли способ генерации фейковых JSON-обьектов (fake plain JSON objects) по `mongoose`-схеме?

Comment: К сожалению, блоки кода в тройках ` на SE не работают. Только отступ на 4 пробела вправо. И внутристрочные блоки, обрамляемые одиночными `.

Comment: Это Node.js код, Что такое SE?

Comment: Меня интересует вопрос, как правильно тестировать код, использующий `mongoose` модели

Comment: StackExchange, частью которого является StackOverflow на русском, и я про разметку в вашем вопросе =) Вы уже всё исправили в разметке, спасибо.

Comment: теперь вопрос, как выйти на русскоязычных людей, которые писали тесты для кода, который использует   `mongoose`,  В частности на [Валерия Карпова](https://github.com/vkarpov15)

Comment: На гитхабе указан его email.

Comment: хмм.. В книге `Web Development With MongoDB`  в разделе `Testing a model` указывается ,  что модели тоже нужно тестировать